# почему ширина li не может быть 33% и почему background-color не можеть сделать фон на весь li по классу callto

Tags: html, css, width, ul, background

почему ширина li не может быть 33% и почему background-color не можеть сделать фон на весь li по классу callto

```css
ul{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  width:600px;
  background:green;
}
.item_footer{
  border:1px solid black;
}
.item_footer span{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.item_footer li{
  width: 31.8%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding:auto auto;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  height:40px;
}
.item_footer li:nth-child(2){
  border-left:1px solid black;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  background-color:gray;
  color:dodgerblue;
}
.item_footer a{
  color:white;
}
.item_footer ul{
  margin:0;
}
.callto{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#4dc7ec;
}
```

```html
            <div class="item_footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>
                          546456
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>
                        132456
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="callto">
                        <span><a href="">Заказать звонок</a></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: это из-за того, что при использовании dipslay: inline-block появляется отступ, также используйте reset.css или normalize.css http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-margins Ваш пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/b3kms34s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смотрите тут https://jsfiddle.net/wqo1kjkf/

```
ul{
  width:600px;
  background:green;
  font-size: 0;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item_footer span{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.item_footer li{
  width: 33.33333%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  height:40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item_footer li:nth-child(2){
  border-left:1px solid black;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  background-color:gray;
  color:dodgerblue;
}
.item_footer a{
  color:white;
}
.item_footer ul{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
.callto{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#4dc7ec;
}
```

немного изменил цсс